# Mongoose userModel is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm pretty new with nodejs and mongoDB. I have created a registration and user schema but it doesn't recognize `this` and send the following error:

> ReferenceError: userModel is not defined

When I trace the error, I found that it doesn't recognize **this** keyword.

Here is `user.js` code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    teamName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    faculty: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) return next(err)
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
})

var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = userModel;
```

`server.js`

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    var newUser = {
        teamName: req.body.teamName,
        faculty: req.body.faculty,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    userModel.create(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('[Registratoin]: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log(user)
            console.log('[Registration]: Done');
            // req.session.userID = user._id;
            res.redirect('/scoreboard')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: show how u call it

Comment: @bxN5 I edit my post

Comment: Can you include how are you importing the `userModel` in your route please?

Comment: @1010101 Yes, I have include it like var userModel = requrie('the_path')

Comment: Could you `console.log(userModel)` in the route. Does it return the model or `undefined`?

Comment: @1010101 yeah! it returns **undefined** unfortunately :(

Comment: No worries, it probably is something minor. Double check the path you're importing the module from. (Maybe showing us more details about relevant directory structure or share the whole route file excluding other request methods will let us help more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` keyword in the pre-save hook in your model is not the issue.

> ReferenceError: userModel is not defined

[`ReferenceError: "x" is not defined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined) means that the `userModel` is `undefined` from the scope you're calling it from. (Thus you're referencing a non-existent value)

> I have include it like `var userModel = require('the_path')`

As you're requiring and exporting the `userModel` correctly. I would double check the path you're importing the module from.